# Stanford corenlp interactive tregex tool results differ from the constituency parse

Tags: stanford-nlp

Can anyone explain why nlp tags from tregex response differs from the tags obtained in constituency parse as shown in the figure below.

[image]

In the above figure, **engineer** is tagged as **NN** by *constituency parse* annotator, but *tregex* outputs it as **NNP**.

Is it because the annotator pipeline used to perform constituency parse uses a different parse model compared to the pipeline used to perform tregex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears different pipelines are being used.

When you run the standard annotation process it will use the pipeline you specify, which it appears in your example includes the `pos` annotator.  Since the `pos` annotator's tags are being used, you are seeing the `NN`.

When you submit a `tregex` request, it is simply running a pipeline with `tokenize,ssplit,parse` (you can see this in the code for StanfordCoreNLPServer.java , which has a specific tregex handler)

This means it is using the constituency parser's part of speech tagging, which produces a different result than the dedicated part-of-speech tagger's results.  In this case the constituency parser applies the tag of `NNP`.  I should note if you use the shift reduce parser it will require the part of speech tags to be provided by the part of speech tagger, whereas the lexical parser has the ability to create it's own part of speech tags.

Comment: Thankx, I thought so.